# Adding to row in MySQL if it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

When adding a row to a table, but first checking to see if it exists first Which would be the most efficient way of handling this?

Would it be a case of query to see if it exist, if not then insert.

Or using on duplicate?

Or simply replace (Would this work, if the row did not exist)?

Thanks

Comment: Define the criteria for *checking to see if it exists*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: Maybe, I didnt explain very well sorry. I was kind of meaning how best to go about it would checking to see it exists first be the best route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the fastest way in MySQL:

```
REPLACE into table (col1, col2) values(1, 'ABC')
```

EDIT:

MySQL will delete the row if it does exist and insert a new one.

Comment: Yes. It would insert a new row then.

Comment: This will insert the record anyway REPLACE = DELETE + INSERT

Comment: no a delete but an UPDATE, which means also that it will not do update if the fields are equals

Comment: Would this query still work with PHP mysql_insert_id? If the row existed, obviously it would not insert, would I still be abel to pull the id from the existing row without having to run another query?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `INSERT IGNORE` see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) or `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Answer (score 0):

depends what you mean by 'exists' if there is a unique field you can check against such as 'email' or 'login' then you can just try the insert and mysql raise error if exists, otherwise you'd do the replace as juergen d just suggested.

**NB: don't use replace if you wanted your timestamps for any reason (such as if they're used in encrypted passwords or salt**